# SendGrid emails ending up as spam - particularly in Outlook

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sendgrid

The sendgrid emails sent from my .net mvc app are ending up as spam. Particularly in Outlook. Below is the code I have in IdentityConfig.cs to send a sendgrid message for email confirmation. In the register action in account controller i just stripped down the line below to remove the text and html around the callbackUrl so that the email body just contains a link and no text or html.

register action:

```
await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", callbackUrl);
```

IdentityConfig.cs

```
var registeredUser = message.Destination;
var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_APIKEY");
var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
var msg = new SendGridMessage(); 
msg.SetFrom(new EmailAddress("team@thewebsite.com", "The team @ thewebsite"));
msg.SetSubject(message.Subject);      
msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(message.Destination));
msg.AddContent(MimeType.Text, message.Body);
var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

Is there anything I can add or change re: the way the above email is sent to prevent the likelihood it'll end up in a spam folder?

Cheers.